# Adjacency List representation of a graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching

I am looking to draw a graph knowing a simple adjacency representation of the graph like:

```
 A = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5}, {5}}
```

Where `A` is my Adjacency List.  I was thinking I could use `Graph[]` and maybe some kind of pattern matching:

```
 Graph[{_\[DirectedEdge]_}]
```

I am also not familiar with patterns in mathematica (the "_" that gets used a lot but has been hard for me to understand).

Comment: Are you missing one sub-list? You got 5 vertexes but 4 sub-lists.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov you are 100% correct.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Adjacency list**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) "...is a collection of unordered lists, one for each vertex in the graph. Each list describes the set of neighbors of its vertex."

I will modify your list slightly to have a bit more interesting graph:

```
A = {{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 4, 3}};
```

Then define a function:

```
el[x_] := Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[First[#2] -> #1] &, x]]
```

And build your graph:

```
Graph[el[A], GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: My only issue is that my adjacency lists are defined such that the first element is the vertex and each subsequent element represents the edges.  This definition would remove all of the 1-cycles in your implementation.

Comment: This is also a great example of neat mathematica programming but I don't understand what you are doing.  Could you explain a little of what is going on?

Comment: if first element in your list is the starting vertex, then you could do Graph[Flatten[Thread[#1 \[DirectedEdge] {##2}] & @@@ A]]

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz you would need to look up in the documentation how the functions work. Start with `MapIndexed`, then `Thread`, then `Flatten`. The main idea here is that you are building a `Graph` out of list of edges. To construct list of edges you need to connect index of the sub-list (vertex) with its elements (neighbor vertexes) by an edge `->`. That what `MapIndexed` do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also construct the `AdjacencyMatrix` associated with `A` and use it with `AdjacencyGraph`:

```
am = SparseArray[Join @@ (Thread /@ MapIndexed[{First@#2, #} &, A]) ->  1]; 
AdjacencyGraph[am, GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]